# Does the second law of thermodynamics apply to parallel universes or higher dimensional universes?

Tags: thermodynamics, universe, spacetime-dimensions

Does the second law of thermodynamics apply to parallel universes and universes of higher dimensions?

Comment: In science fiction, one is free to assume anything, and it will depend on how mathematically rigorous the imagined universe is created.  In extensions of the mathematical description of our universe this is a questions to be mathematically explored by the person studying the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several kinds of "parallel universes" in the literature, and the second law of thermodynamics does apply to nearly all of them.

Note that separate universes in a multiverse model are *separate*: they form thermodynamically isolated systems. Hence you only need to think about thermodynamics in each individual universe - there is no flow of mass, energy, or information between them.

There are some subtle points. Tegmark Level I multiverses consist of a single spatially infinite space-time, where there are going to be local random repetitions of any configuration. They are in principle able to encounter each other, but in practice the distance of separation is so vast that their light-cones will never intersect: they are entirely separate.

Except that in an infinite world with random initial configurations you will occasionally get two next to each other, having some potentially nontrivial interactions. In fact, you also have the problem of random initial conditions or later random fluctuations causing deviations from thermodynamics in sufficiently large or long-lived worlds. This was noted by Boltzman and others long ago. Thermodynamics holds in the large and on average, but there are random deviations from it and in "big" enough worlds there are going to be arbitrarily big deviations... except that they form a microscopically tiny fraction of all that is going on. So it still makes sense to say thermodynamics applies, even though there are "miracles" happening here and there. In a sufficiently big casino there are going to be jackpots happening all the time, yet the house always gets the money.

Level IV multiverses where all mathematically possible systems exist have some where thermodynamics applies and some where it does not apply. Because of the trouble of defining measures over this kind of infinite class it is not possible to speak about whether it applies "on average". If one looks at just computable universes measures can be defined, but I am uncertain if it is known whether thermodynamics holds or not in that setting.

Higher dimensional worlds with physics like ours would have fairly normal thermodynamics. It is not defined in terms of spacetime dimensionality.